# Передача больших объемов данных между активностями

Tags: android

У меня есть ArrayList объектов Parcelable, которые необходимо передать следующей активности для отображения во ViewPager. Однако когда объектов становится достаточно много, вылетает java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to find app for caller android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy when publishing content providers . Я так понимаю, это происходит из-за слишком большого размера ArrayList. Что с этим можно сделать? Пока нашел решение только с использованием статической переменной.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно выгрузить в файл или БД. А в Intent передать ссылку на файл (или id в базе). При открытии другой Activity прочитать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я тоже недавно до этого додумался, просто сохранял весь json с элементами в sharedpreferences и при переходе на новую активность заново его парсил